# yield return null exits the iteration

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
   IEnumerator loadScene(string sceneName)
{
    AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
    while (!operation.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log(operation.progress);
        yield return null;
    }


}
```

I am using above code to load scene. It loads the scene perfectly but operation.progress is running only once. It just prints one value 0.05 something.

If I use the below code it does not even load the scene.

```
IEnumerator loadScene(string sceneName)
{
    AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
    operation.allowSceneActivation = false;
    while (!operation.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log(operation.progress);'
       if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.9f)
        {
          asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This is even suggested on unity documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html

Comment: You could potentially use a `do{ }while();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem is loading scene happens too fast and progress goes to 0.9 right away if you want more control over it you can try this:

```
    float time = 0;
    AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Rotation");
    asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
    {
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log(asyncLoad.progress+" time is"+time);
        if (time > 4.0f)
            asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true;
        yield return null;

    }
```

It will load the scene after 4 seconds and if you want this coroutine to keep working after new scene is loaded add `DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject)` in `Start()`

I wanted to add this explanation as well after seeing the confusion in the comments. `yield return null` does not break or return the coroutine. It just returns after your while is executed once and then coroutine continues from where it left in the next frame. The problem in this example is his scene loads in 1 frame so coroutine ends really fast. Normally with `yield return null` you do 1 iteration in each frame. I hope this helps good luck!

Comment: Yes the issue was the gameObject is being destroyed now it is working. Thanks for help mate.

Answer (score 0):

<del>That would definitely appear to be an error in that code sample.  By design, `yield return null;` exits the entire coroutine (in the same way a 'return;' exits a void method).

Try replacing it with `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();`</del>

Comment: Then whats the difference between yield break and yield return null? And I have checked few youtube tutorials as well in those as well they user yield return null.

Comment: Are you sure about that? From my understanding coroutine will return after every iteration and then continue from where it left with `yield return null`

Comment: I just checked with yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); same result as yield return null

Comment: Well i try the same thing and it probably loads too fast so next time you are in coroutine your progress is already 1

Comment: Indeed.  I was thinking of `yield return break;`

Comment: @AliKanat even if it loads scene that fast then to it should at least run the code after the while loop right. Say if I put a log after while loop it should be printed right? or yield return null just exit from the whole coroutine?

Comment: It would normally print but my guess is the object you attach the script with coroutine will be destroyed when the new scene is loaded so it can not print it and i just tested it with `DontDestroyOnLoad` that is exactly what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

1). My bet is that operation is done for some other reason. Add

```
Debug.Log( $"is operation done:{ operation.isDone }, progress:{ operation.progress }" );
```

just after your loop to test just that

2). Debug if coroutine was stopped by something external (like object destruction)

```
void OnEnable ()
{
    Debug.Log( $"{ name } enabled" , gameObject );
}

void OnDisable()
{
    Debug.Log( $"{ name } disabled" , gameObject );
}

void OnDestroy ()
{
    Debug.Log( $"{ name } destroyed" );
}
```

Comment: I have tried putting log after the loop but it does not print any of those logs. I guess for some reason yield return null is exiting the flow from loadScne coroutine.

Comment: No. Definately not by coroutine itself. Coroutines may stop itself this way only when your gameobject becomes destroyed od disabled (not in all cases tho)

Comment: Add these to investigate this:


    void OnEnable ()
    {
        Debug.Log( $"{ name } enabled" , gameObject );
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        Debug.Log( $"{ name } disabled" , gameObject );
    }

    void OnDestroy ()
    {
        Debug.Log( $"{ name } destroyed" );
    } EDIT: I added this code to main answer body where it's formatted properly

Comment: Yeah just found out that my gameObject was being destroyed that's why I am not getting the logs. Btw Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try yield break.

```
int count = 0; 

StartCoroutine(CountCoroutine ());

IENumerator CountCoroutine () { 

    count++;

    if (count > 10) { 
         yield break; 
    } 

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
}
```